# Word searching engine

Tags: java, android

I work on game in which player gathers word from letters.All i need to do is to check if word exists in language or search in dictionary.Best  of what I found is Hunspell but it wont work because I want to search words only in nominative case.Is there some others tool that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to quickly go through thousands of words and search for a word in it, you can use Redis. It stores the data in memory and it is extremely fast.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of dictionary words off the internet and save them to a text file.

Read the file into your program and save it in.a Collection

Search the list for what you need.

Comment: It's a good idea.But it will be slow

Comment: Searching a list is not a slow process. Even when it's 5k words.

Comment: ArrayList.contains(word)